# List refresh, item renderer in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list, action, itemrenderer

I have a List and the item renderer displays an image and text from xml (news rss). 
Not all news have an image. Whenever you scroll the list, and the item renderer refreshes, it move images of news of a position, so the news "1" have the image of news "2", and the news "2" have the image of news "3" ecc., but the text (the title of news not move) .  how can I do?
thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but I guess overriding the `set data` method and changing the source of the image component in the item renderer would fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're using a custom item renderer?

Where are you setting the icon? If you set the icon in this function :

`[override] public function set data(value:Object)`

it should update with the scroll.